# Lubuntu font too small to read

Tags: xorg, lubuntu, fonts, dpi

My Lubuntu font size suddenly turned extremely tiny (upper case characters are 4 pixels high) for some reason. The only possible change I can think of is I turned on desktop sharing (vino) in the session settings. The system fonts is Ubuntu 11. How can I fix it?

Changing system font size actually doesn't do anything at all. Texts are still 4 pixels high.

Comment: websites are ok... it's just affecting desktop fonts

Answer (score 3):

Strange that my DPI got changed mid-use...

Fixed it with:

```
Option         "UseEdidDpi" "False"
Option         "DPI" "168 x 168"
```

in xorg.conf